# Find all unread conversations in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I am making a group chat conversation schema using mongoose but I have been having trouble with a query for the past few days. My goal here is to find all the unread conversations of a user.

My schema looks like this:

```
const ConversationSchema = new Schema(
  {
    participants: [{
      user: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      lastViewed: Date, // the last date the user checked the conversation
    }],
    updatedAt: Date,
  }
);
```

And this is the simplified sample data:

```
   {
     participants: [
       {
         user: 'A',
         lastViewed: 'Jan 11'
       },
       {
         user: 'B',
         lastViewed: 'Jan 13'
       },
     ],
     updatedAt: 'Jan 13',
   }
```

For me, a conversation would be considered unread for a user if:

- the user is in the participant array
- and the conversation `updatedAt` value is greater than the participant's `lastViewed` value

Lastly, my mongoose find function looks like this

```
const conversations = await conversationModel.find({
  'participants.user': user.id,
  $expr: {
    $gt: ['updatedAt', 'participants.user.lastViewed'],
  },
});
```

So when I try to query for user B's unread conversations, I should be expecting an empty `[]` result as `Jan 13 = Jan 13` but I am still getting the conversation in the results. I think the problem is in the `$expr` argument but I am unsure what to add as it deals with an array. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use dollar sign within `$expr` when referring fields but this won't solve your issue. The problem is that you're trying to find particular user so there can be a situation when user `A` exists but `lastViewed` of other user is lower than `updatedAt` (separate conditions).

It's better to use [$let](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/let/) and [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/index.html) to find your user first and then apply your conditions on that particular subdocument:

```
db.collection.find({
    $expr: {
        $let: {
            vars: { user: { $arrayElemAt: [ { $filter: { input: "$participants", cond: { $eq: [ "$$this.user", "A" ] } } }, 0 ] }},
            in: {
                $and: [
                    { $ne: [ "$$user", null ] },
                    { $gt: [ "$updatedAt", "$$user.lastViewed" ] }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
})
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/D0NLbKTFsFH)

I would also recommend to convert your dates from strings to ISODate formats to avoid any issues like `Jan 13` vs `Jan 9` comparison.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed and thanks for links and the suggestion. I'll look into it